# Why does R automatically enter Browser mode upon convergence failure?

Tags: r, rstudio, plyr, lme4, purrr

I'm conducting simulation-based power analyses in R. I run R through RStudio (0.98.932), using the functions `plyr::rdply` and `lme4::glmer` to generate the data and fit the models, respectively (see end of reproducible example below for R environment and package versions).

The procedure is to randomly generate a data set of a given parametrization and fit a model to it. Every now and then, however, the model fails to converge. When this happens with the following warnings

> [1] "unable to evaluate scaled gradient"
>   [2] "Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues"

R enters Browser mode and I have to manually intervene (e.g. press `c`) to go back into the simulation loop. This is a real pain because I need to run thousands of iterations over several days, but every time it encounters this particular convergence error it will stop until I press a key.

Is there a way to avoid R entering Browser mode? I store all the warnings that arise in each simulation, so the only problem I have is that I have to intervene manually when this specific convergence failure takes place. I've tried using the `purrr::quietly` and `purrr::safely` functions, but with no success (see example in code below).

Here's a MWE that works on my computer (I use `set.seed` for reproducibility so I hope it leads to the same result independently of package versions etc). In the example I apply the same logic, but different and simpler parametrizations, as I use in the actual simulations:

```
library(lme4)
library(plyr)
library(purrr)

# function to generate data that will lead to convergence failure
mini_simulator <- function() {
  nb_items <- 10  # observations per subject
  nb_subj <- 10  # subjects per group
  generate_data <- function() {
    A <- rbinom(nb_items * nb_subj, 1, .99)
    B <- rbinom(nb_items * nb_subj, 1, .8)
    simdata <- data.frame(
      Group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = nb_items * nb_subj),
      Subj = rep(1 : (nb_subj * 2), each = nb_items),
      Items = 1:nb_items,
      Response = c(A, B)
      )
  }
}

# Sanity check that the function is generating data appropriately.
# d should be a dataframe with 200 obs. of 4 variables
d <- mini_simulator()()
head(d, 3)
# Group Subj Items Response
# 1     A    1     1        1
# 2     A    1     2        1
# 3     A    1     3        1
rm(d)

## Functions to fit model

# basic function to fit model on simulated data
fit_model <- function(data_sim) {
  fm <- glmer(
    formula = Response ~ Group + (1|Subj) + (1|Items),
    data = data_sim, family = "binomial")
  out <- data.frame(summary(fm)$coef)
  out
}

# similar but using purrr::quietly (also tried purrr::safely with no success)
# see http://r4ds.had.co.nz/lists.html section "Dealing with failure"
fit_model_quietly <- function(data_sim) {
  purrr_out <- purrr::quietly(glmer)(
    formula = Response ~ Group + (1|Subj) + (1|Items),
    data = data_sim, family = "binomial")
  fm <- purrr_out$result
  out <- data.frame(summary(fm)$coef)
  # keeps track of convergence failures and other warnings
  out$Warnings <- paste(unlist(purrr_out$warnings), collapse = "; ")
  out
}

# this seed creates the problematic convergence failure on the first evaluation
# of rdply
set.seed(2)
# When I run the next line R goes into Browse mode and I need to enter "c"
# in order to continue
simulations <- plyr::rdply(.n = 3, fit_model(mini_simulator()()))
simulations

# problem persists using the quietly adverb from purrr
set.seed(2)
simulations <- plyr::rdply(.n = 3, fit_model_quietly(mini_simulator()()))
simulations

# sessionInfo()

# R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
# Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
# 
# locale:
#   [1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252    LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252
# [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    
# 
# attached base packages:
#   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
#   [1] purrr_0.2.1  plyr_1.8.1   lme4_1.1-8   Matrix_1.1-4
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#   [1] grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29 magrittr_1.5    MASS_7.3-35     minqa_1.2.4     nlme_3.1-118    nloptr_1.0.4   
# [8] Rcpp_0.11.3     splines_3.1.2   tools_3.1.2
```

## Update (based on r2evans' comments)

On both my computers `options("error")` yields

> (function () 
>   {
>       .rs.breakOnError(TRUE)
>   })()

That seems to be some kind of RStudio default and indeed seems to make R go into browser mode when encountering a `stop()`call (I see this can be changed in the graphical interface via the menu toolbar Debug > On Error > ...). Anyway, when I set `options(error = NULL)`, the problem disappears. Here's the new (simplfied) example which works just fine (both in this minimal example and also when applied to the actual simulations):

```
library(lme4)
library(plyr)
library(purrr)

options(error=NULL)

## Function to generate data
# Generates data that will lead to convergence failure
mini_simulator <- function() {
  nb_items <- 10  # observations per subject
  nb_subj <- 10  # subjects per group
  generate_data <- function() {
    A <- rbinom(nb_items * nb_subj, 1, .99)
    B <- rbinom(nb_items * nb_subj, 1, .8)
    simdata <- data.frame(
      Group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = nb_items * nb_subj),
      Subj = rep(1 : (nb_subj * 2), each = nb_items),
      Items = 1:nb_items,
      Response = c(A, B)
    )
  }
}

## Function to fit model
# Fits model on simulated data with purrr::quietly to capture warnings
# (http://r4ds.had.co.nz/lists.html section "Dealing with failure")
fit_model_quietly <- function(data_sim) {
  purrr_out <- purrr::quietly(glmer)(
    formula = Response ~ Group + (1|Subj) + (1|Items),
    data = data_sim, family = "binomial")
  fm <- purrr_out$result
  out <- data.frame(summary(fm)$coef)
  # keeps track of convergence failures and other warnings
  out$Warnings <- paste(unlist(purrr_out$warnings), collapse = "; ")
  out
}

# this seed creates the problematic convergence failure on the first evaluation
# of rdply
set.seed(2)
simulations <- plyr::rdply(.n = 3, fit_model_quietly(mini_simulator()()))
simulations
```

Comment: I'm biased but I think you should check out the SimDesign package. It is a very useful set of tools for tackling this sort of problem (and deals with non-convergence issues implicitly).  It is on CRAN.

Comment: Does this have something to do with `options("error")`? On my machine, your code just gives an error (`Error: 'data' not found, and some variables missing from formula environment`), so if you have previously done `options(error = browser)`, then that could explain the behavior.

Comment: @Twitch_City Thanks for the advice. I'll definitely check it out. Still, I'd like to know what causes this behaviour and how I can avoid it.

Comment: @r2evans Hmm, I haven't changed anything to `options("error")`. To me your error looks more like it has to do with not having generated the data with the function `mini_simulator`. Have you installed all the necessary packages, listed in the beginning of the example? Actually I would appreciate knowing if my example is reproducible to begin with. Help appreciated

Comment: As I said, your code gives me an error, not a debugger, so it is possibly reproducible: if I set `options(error=browser)` then I get similar behavior. If somehow your option had been set then that would explain it. Read `?options` for more info. What does `options("error")` tell you?

Comment: Try `options(error=NULL)` and rerun your code. My guess is that you will see the error and no debugger. If not, let us know by editing your question with the new-found info!

Comment: I'm rerunning the code, and (sigh) I cannot reproduce my previous error. I had checked the results of `mini_simulator` (out of curiosity) and it was working the first time as it is now. **However**, If I set `options(warn=2, error=browser)`, then on execution I enter the browser (`Browse[1]>`), as commanded. (BTW, did you know you get different warnings in 32bit versus 64bit? 32: `Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio`; 64: `unable to evaluate scaled gradient`. Mathematically concerning.)

Comment: @r2evans As I wrote in my update, your suggestion seems to solve the problem of going into browser mode. However, I do not feel that I've grasped what is really going on here. For example, if I wrap my `glmer` call with `purrr::safely` I do not get any traces of an error message saved into the object created by `purrr::safely`, which I find strange if R is going into browser mode _because_ it encountered an error. I see that in my 64bit machine the problem occurs with the function `chol.default`, while in the 32bit it occurs with `chol`. I suppose the different warnings are related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Browser

This sounds like a combination of `options` that triggers warnings and errors to immediately enter the `browser` debugger.

```
func <- function(type = "none") {
  if (type == "warning") {
    warning("impending doom")
  } else if (type == "error") {
    stop("doom")    
  }
  type
}

func()
# [1] "none"
func("warning")
# Warning in func("warning") : impending doom
# [1] "warning"
func("error")
# Error in func("error") (from #5) : doom
```

Two relevant options, `warn` and `error`. See `?options` for more info.

```
options("warn")
# $warn
# [1] 1
```

This converts a warning to an error:

```
options(warn=2)
func("warning")
# Error in func("warning") (from #3) : (converted from warning) impending doom
```

Now with the `error` option, we can do something with that error:

```
options(warn=1, error=browser)
func("warning")
# Warning in func("warning") : impending doom
# [1] "warning"
func("error")
# Error in func("error") (from #5) : doom
# Browse[1]> 
c
```

So converting warnings to errors and catching the error:

```
options(warn=2, error=browser)
func("warning")
# Error in func("warning") (from #3) : (converted from warning) impending doom
# Browse[1]> 
c
```

I believe this is what was happening to you.

### `Purrr`

As for why `purrr::quietly` appears to be doing things a little off, I can confirm that it is bypassing or ignoring the intended upgrade from warning to error:

```
quietfunc <- quietly(func)
str(quietfunc("warning"))
# List of 4
#  $ result  : chr "warning"
#  $ output  : chr ""
#  $ warnings: chr "impending doom"
#  $ messages: chr(0) 
options(warn=2, error=browser)
str(quietfunc("warning"))     # no browser!
# List of 4
#  $ result  : chr "warning"
#  $ output  : chr ""
#  $ warnings: chr "impending doom"
#  $ messages: chr(0) 
str(quietfunc("error"))       # yes browser
# Error in .f(...) (from #5) : doom
# Browse[1]> 
c
```

Whereas a simple warning in the function is not caught by `safely` (nor is it intended to be):

```
options(warn=1)
str(safefunc("warning"))      # warning is not "captured" by purrr::safely
# Warning in .f(...) : impending doom
# List of 2
#  $ result: chr "warning"
#  $ error : NULL
```

Perhaps [this is a bug](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/issues)?

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really helpful. First, it solved my problem. Second, it was very instructive to gain insight into the workings of `options` and how errors and warnings are handled in R.